# Isomorphism between $H_k(X,x_0)$ and $\tilde H_k (X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, intuition

I can prove this using the long exact sequence of relative homology groups. Is there a way to understand this isomorphism intuitively?

Answer (score 1):

Relative homology $H_k(X,A)$ is when you allow cycles to have boundaries in $A$ (rather than requiring the boundary to be $0$), and when a cycle is nullhomologous if it is homologous to something in $A$.  When $A$ is a single point, things become simpler.

When $k>0$, a cycle whose boundary is contained in a point has a degenerate boundary, which is homologous to $0$, so $H_k(X,x_0)$ is the same as $H_k(X)$ and $\widetilde{H}_k(X)$.  (The latter is because reduced homology has the same chain groups as $H_k(X)$ except at the $-1$ grading.)

The interesting case is $k=0$.  $0$-cycles are points, and two points are homologous if there is a path between them. And, in relative homology, a point is nullhomologous if there is a path to $x_0$.  This kills one of the connected components.  $\widetilde{H}_0(X)$ kills off a path component in a slightly different way, which is by saying that the sum of the coefficients of the points must be zero.  The map $\widetilde{H}_0(X)\to H_0(X,x_0)$ can be thought of as setting the coefficients of points in the same path component of $x_0$ to $0$.  The inverse to this is to sum the coefficients of the points in a cycle representative for $H_0(X,x_0)$, then subtract that amount of $x_0$.

Comment: I don't understand this: When $k>0$, a cycle whose boundary is contained in a point has a degenerate boundary, which is homologous to $0$, so $H_k(X,x_0)$ is the same as $H_k(X)$. Do you mean that if we take $\sigma\in H_k(X,x_0)$, then $\sigma = \alpha+ C_k(x_0)+Im\partial_{k+1}^{(X,x_0)} $, with $\alpha\in C_k(X)$ and $\partial \alpha \in C_{k-1}(x_0)$, and since $H_{k-1}(x_0)=0$ if $k\geq 2$ , $\partial\alpha$ is homologous to $0$ in $H_{k-1}(x_0)=0$? How does this lead to the conclusion that $H_k(X,x_0)=H_k(X)$?

Comment: I guess I gave you surjectivity and not injectivity.  What I had in mind is that any cycle $C_k(X)$ which ends up being nullhomologous in $C_k(X,x_0)$ has its boundary being in $C_k(x_0)$, and such a boundary is nullhomologous, so the cycle was actually nullhomologous in $C_k(X)$.  This is essentially the proof of the long exact sequence of the pair specialized to $(X,x_0)$.  (Consider what I said about degenerate boundaries to be my intuition for the proof.)

Answer (score 0):

Given $A\hookrightarrow_{j} X$ we have by definition $ C(X,A)=C(X)/C(A) $, from the long exact sequence and the group isomorphism theorems we get $H_n(X,A)=\frac{\{\alpha\in C_n(X)|\partial\alpha\in jC_{n-1}(A)\}}{\partial C_{n+1}(X)+C_n(A)}$. In this way you can have a more concrete way to understand the homology of the pair.